# Send email with attached pdf using html

Tags: html, pdf, salesforce

I am working on the email template using HTML, and the requirement is to send an email with the attached pdf. PDF is there in the "images and media" storage but it is not being attached. Although images are being attached.

I expect that while sending an email, email should have attached pdf also. A recipient should get the pdf file in the email.

Comment: What is the backend?

Comment: We are creating the application on Salesforce.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/where-are-my-attachements

Comment: Thanks, soorapadman. However, i am looking to fetch pdf files dynamically through HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

We could Achieve it through VF Email Template with following,

1. If your Attachment is static(Like pdf,img and etc) - Go with standard **Attach File** option below the VF email template
2. If your attachment has dynamic merge fields - Proceed with below hack, you can bundle your images from static resources or from VF Component.

   `<messaging:emailTemplate subject="subject" recipientType="User" 
      relatedToType="objName">
      <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
      Email template Content goes here...
      </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
     <messaging:attachment filename="Attachment Name" renderAs="pdf">
      Email Template Attachment Content goes here....
     </messaging:attachment>
     </messaging:emailTemplate>`